# Can I tell TestDisk to ignore filesystem?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery, testdisk

I recently formatted a FAT32 external hard drive to ext4. After realising this was, in my case, a mistake I now want to attempt to recover the data whilst **keeping the folder structure intact** How can I do this in Ubuntu 13.04? Is there a way to have TestDisk search the whole disk/all data instead of just known partitions?

I'm aware that PhotoRec ignores filesystem but it recovers files with no folder structure and with odd names like f9189667.txt f9189677.txt etc

Answer (score 1):

Using PhotoRec, enable the expert mode, start a recovery, answer Yes when asked about FAT unformat.

Comment: Your answer is not clear. Does this address the OP's issue concerning Photorec and odd file names?